# How do you output FFmpeg video file encoding real-time via PHP -- primarily on Linux with Nvidia?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, php, nvidia

I have a simple FFmpeg script that outputs an MP4 fine on Linux with Nvidia. This takes roughly 6 seconds to process before I can show it on the PHP page (in the HTML5 video player). I suspect there are ways I could show the video output in real-time (i.e. during encoding). Does anyone know how I would go about doing this? My objective is to apply your solution to scripts that take much longer to process (i.e. output) and I very much want to show the output in real-time if possible.

- The script below is run via a PHP shell_exec request on a Linux server...

ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i bgVid.mp4 -loop 1 -i mainImg.png -loop 1 -i whtBlk4Txt.png -loop 1 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=407:-1,fade=st=4:d=2:alpha=1,fade=out:st=13:d=2:alpha=1,format=yuva420p,hwupload[A];[2]scale=960:540,fade=st=4:d=2:alpha=1,fade=out:st=13:d=2:alpha=1,format=yuva420p,hwupload[B];[2]drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf:fontsize=70.588235294118:x=(((w/2)-(tw/2)) + (-229.00000381469727)):y=163: fontcolor=black:text='Line One Test',drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf:fontsize=35.294117647059:x=(((w/2)-(tw/2)) + (-229.00000381469727)):y=235: fontcolor=black:text='Line Two Test',drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf:fontsize=70.588235294118:x=(((w/2)-(tw/2)) + (-229.00000381469727)):y=253: fontcolor=black:text='Line 3 Test',drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf:fontsize=35.294117647059:x=(((w/2)-(tw/2)) + (-229.00000381469727)):y=324: fontcolor=black:text='Line 4 Test',fade=st=4:d=2:alpha=1,fade=out:st=13:d=2:alpha=1,format=yuva420p,hwupload[C];[3]scale=150:-1,format=yuva420p,hwupload[D];[0:v]scale_npp=format=yuv420p[main];[main][A]overlay_cuda=515.9861145019531:79.94444274902344[base1t];[base1t][B]overlay_cuda=1:1[base2t];[base2t][C]overlay_cuda=1:1[base3tx];[base3tx][D]overlay_cuda=10:10[out]" -map "[out]" -ss 0 -to 15 -c:v h264_nvenc -c:a copy -flags +global_header -preset fast -y vidOut.mp4

Comment: If this is possible, your user will probably loose the possibility of "navigation", ie. skip forward, backward.  That's no problem?

Comment: Thanks, Gerald...  The objective will be to append each FFmpeg script output to a master m3u8 streaming playlist via ts files. I think I found a solution for the initial question above... but now looking for the ability to create ongoing ts files via separate FFmpeg scripts that can be appended to a master playlist.